# Does flutter support both ARCore and ARKit plugin in a single app?

Tags: flutter, arkit, arcore

I'm trying Flutter AR app for cross platform, is it possible to use both plugin in a single app. With single code base(ARKit code) will it work for android platform and vise versa or do we need to work independently for individual platform  ?

```
dependencies:
   arcore_flutter_plugin: ^0.0.2+1
   arkit_plugin: ^0.3.0
```

Comment: Arcore supports both IOS and Android operating systems. See reference https://developers.google.com/ar/devices. Can I know why do you need to implement separate plugins?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, I have managed to combine both plugins in one flutter app so that ARCore runs on Android devices and ARKit on iOS.

To get started, just follow the tutorials to create an arkit app and an arcore app. Then create a new flutter project with both plugins. For the first version, I put the [arcore_flutter_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/arcore_flutter_plugin) code in a class I called *ArCoreState* (extending State for the app) and the [arkit_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/arkit_plugin) code in another class, *ArKitState*.

The main.dart was then simply

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MultiPlatformApp()));

class MultiPlatformApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override State<StatefulWidget> createState() => 
     Platform.isAndroid ? ArCoreState() : ArKitState();
}
```

When you have that running, you have a cross platform AR app, even if it has only one single line of shared code!

Comment: But it is not valid for OPENGL and rendering 3d objects. Isn't that?  check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62422439/importing-3d-model-into-flutter-app-and-textures-not-showing-up

Comment: Hi @AbdulSaleem. You can't write OpenGL code directly in Flutter, but ARCore uses OpenGLES and you can use Dart code with ARCore. On iOS, I'd recommend using Metal – Apple is not really supporting OpenGL anymore. I have managed to hook up an OpenGL renderer to ARkit a few years ago, but it took a *lot* of effort.

Answer (score 11):

I know this has been asked a while ago now, but the problem is still unchanged.

To everyone ending up here because they are trying to develop a cross-platform AR app with Flutter: Check out this [GitHub Issue Thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22860).

Among others, I'm currently working on a Flutter plugin that supports both ARCore and ARKit with a common interface, so people can write proper cross-platform apps with shared code and functionality. I'll be posting updates into the GitHub discussion linked above!

**EDIT**

The plugin is now available at: https://pub.dev/packages/ar_flutter_plugin

Comment: But it is not valid for OPENGL and rendering 3d objects. Isn't that?  check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62422439/importing-3d-model-into-flutter-app-and-textures-not-showing-up

Comment: Hey @AbdulSaleem, the project has advanced quite a lot since I posted this, you can check out my plugin here: https://github.com/CariusLars/ar_flutter_plugin 
It supports loading and rendering 3D models for AR experiences both from file and from the web on Android and iOS

Comment: Great ..... Thank you so much for the reference. I am working on a project for the trial of all different products in eCommerce stores using both the back camera and the front camera. In addition, I need to create 3d product ar models via camera for all products. I must complete the project in 2021. Do you suggest I go with flutter or native android/ios/web development? Bundle of thanks in advance ..

Comment: For the products trial: Back camera (placing objects on the floor or on some table) is doable with the plugin right now and works really well with managing the models in a webapp so you don't have to compile them into the app, front camera (and I assume face anchors) currently isn't, but that shouldn't be too hard to implement (not on my current roadmap but would be an awesome pull request if you work on it ;) ). Creating 3D models is a different story, I have 0 experience how to to that, so I guess it depends on how important that is for your app

Comment: If you want to offer both iOS and Android though I would recommend going to Flutter because the actual AR plugin is just a Flutter-wrapper around platform-level code, so you could easily  advance the platform-specific code (that you would develop in either case) and bundle the business logic on the Flutter side which saves you doing it twice. In my experience it takes a bit to get into Flutter and abstract everything to a cross-platform level, but once you get the hang of it it's really useful and saves you a lot of maintenance time

Comment: @Lars - I am so happy you have made a start to unite ARkit and ARcore into one plugin. I was going to start this project myself. I will be in touch to discuss how I can participate. 