# importing 3d model into Flutter app and textures not showing up

Tags: flutter, augmented-reality, arkit, blender

**Problem:** I am using the [**ARKIT**](https://pub.dev/packages/arkit_plugin) package for flutter. I have been having a hard time figuring out how to import the 3d model for my project with the textures included. The package has an example that has textures included (located in the IOS Runner folder) which demonstrates that this is possible with their custom 3d object example (eevee.dae).

**What is the best way to import a model into a flutter app and maintain its textures/materials?**

Comment: This thread might answer the problem. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3778/why-does-the-collada-exporter-not-export-texture-references

Comment: Is This Still Not Possible?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, flutter currently [does not have official support for 3D models](https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/faq#can-i-build-3d-opengl-apps-with-flutter) and the same goes for ARKit and AR-Core. You can draw on the screen using some 3rd party libraries and packages. I think your best bet, in this case, is to reach out to the creator of the package and ask for their assistance.